# Функция  textscan

Tags: python, matlab

Переписываю программу с `MATLAB` на `Python`. Есть ли в `python` аналогичная функция `textscan` (`textscan` - чтение данных из текстового файла, преобразование и запись в массив ячеек) или же придется отдельную функцию писать

Примерный код программы:

```
fid = fopen(las_file);
file = textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n','whitespace', '');
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вам подойдет питоновский [парсер csv файлов](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), не знаю, какой именно формат Вы собираетесь читать, но наверняка сможете найти более подходящие параметры, по сигнатуре csv подходит.